# "Kill" fragment after replace it

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a MainActivity with two tabs (using viewPager). In the second tab I have a mapFragment - Google Maps API. After clicking in a button it would open another fragment. However, the mapFragment is under the fragment (in log I see that the map is re-drawn).

Any suggestion how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `add()` to go to the new fragment, replace it with `replace()`.

See this example:

```
final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
ft.replace(R.id.container, new NewFragment(), "NewFragment"); 
ft.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks. I use `replace()`. But still have that problem.